# Rows are selected differently on document load and on function call

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I was working on my own filter for datatables. To make a long story short, it gets a date value placed in one of the columns and checks it against the current date, and if its value is inferior to our current date then the entire row is deleted. This works perfectly but only on document load. I've tried to trigger my code with a button but it changes the behaviour of my code: instead of identifying rows according to its place in the original data source (in this case the table is written in html directly), it identifies rows according to its place in the current view.

Here is a working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c18mzcox/

In order to check what I'm saying just click the "hide finished" button and check which rows are being deleted (index 0 and 6 from the current view, which is wrong). Then, edit the javascript part and delete the button in line 22 and its corresponding ending in line 75. Refresh and see how this time the rows being deleted are different (index 0 and 6 from the original file, which is what I need). Without any button attached it works as it should. But attaching a button to the code changes the behaviour of row selection...

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready( function () {

$.fn.dataTable.moment('D[ / ]M[ / ]YYYY');  
var table = $('#table_id').DataTable({

    "language": {
        "url": "http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/3cfcc339e89/i18n/Spanish.json"
    },

    "order": [[ 1, "desc" ]],

    dom: 'TC<"clear">lfrtip',

    oTableTools: {
        sSwfPath: "http://cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.3/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
    }

});
    //If you delete this button it behaves as it should...
    $('#btnToggleFinish').click(function(){
        //Getting the current date
        var d = new Date();
        var day = d.getDate();
        var month = d.getMonth();
        var year = d.getFullYear();
        var actualDateObj = new Date();
        actualDateObj.setDate(day);
        actualDateObj.setMonth(month);
        actualDateObj.setYear(year);

        //Selecting the column with the dates
        var idx = table.column(2).data();
        //Getting the amount of rows for the loop
        var rowCount = table.data().length;


            for (var i = 0; rowCount > i; i++)
            {
                //Getting the date values from the table
                var myDay = idx[i].substring(0,2);
                var myMonth = idx[i].substring (5,7);
                var myYear = idx[i].substring (10,14);
                var tableDateObj = new Date();
                tableDateObj.setDate(myDay);
                tableDateObj.setMonth(myMonth-1);
                tableDateObj.setYear(myYear);

                if (actualDateObj > tableDateObj) {
                    table.row(i).nodes().to$().addClass('deleteMe');    
                }   
            }
        table.rows('.deleteMe').remove().draw();
    });
});
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you realise, that when clicking the "Hide Finished" button several times, all the rows are removed? Just asking, because this might be a sign, that your date check is not working as intended.

Comment: @ThorJacobsen I believe the date check is working alright. Just put this inside the last IF statement: alert("tableDateObj: " + tableDateObj); and you'll see it.

It keeps deleting rows because the datecheck reads from the content of the file and not the values you are currently seeing. In the file nothing is deleted, so if you keep pressing the button it will still be deleting rows according to those indexes selected in the date check. But this is a minor issue because in the future the button will be a toggle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a proper answer to the problem, but somewhat it worked for me. Inside the code of the button which activates my filter, I've put a table.destroy(); and just after that I've put once again the constructor of the table before doing all the checks. Now it works as intended. This is not optimised and it does not work 100% because the table is not properly populated again if you want to undo the changes applied by the filter, but there it goes.

```
$(document).ready( function () {


$.fn.dataTable.moment('D[ / ]M[ / ]YYYY');  
var table = $('#table_id').DataTable({

    "language": {
        "url": "http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/3cfcc339e89/i18n/Spanish.json"
    },

    "order": [[ 1, "desc" ]],

    dom: 'TC<"clear">lfrtip',

    oTableTools: {
        sSwfPath: "http://cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.3/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
    }

});

    var hided = false;

    $('#btnToggleFinish').click(function(){

        if (hided == false){

            $(this).html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" aria-hidden="true"></span> Show');
            hided = true;

            table.destroy();

            table = $('#table_id').DataTable({

                "language": {
                    "url": "http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/3cfcc339e89/i18n/Spanish.json"
                },

                "order": [[ 1, "desc" ]],

                dom: 'TC<"clear">lfrtip',

                oTableTools: {
                    sSwfPath: "http://cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.3/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
                }

            });


            var d = new Date();
            var day = d.getDate();
            var month = d.getMonth();
            var year = d.getFullYear();

            var actualDateObj = new Date();
            actualDateObj.setDate(day);
            actualDateObj.setMonth(month);
            actualDateObj.setYear(year);

            var idx = table.column(2).data();

            var rowCount = table.data().length;

                for (var i = 0; rowCount > i; i++)
                {

                    var myDay = idx[i].substring(0,2);
                    var myMonth = idx[i].substring (5,7);
                    var myYear = idx[i].substring (10,14);

                    var tableDateObj = new Date();
                    tableDateObj.setDate(myDay);
                    tableDateObj.setMonth(myMonth-1); 
                    tableDateObj.setYear(myYear);


                    if (actualDateObj > tableDateObj) {

                        table.row(i).nodes().to$().addClass('deleteMe'); 
                    }

                }
            table.rows('.deleteMe').remove().draw();

        }

        else{
            $(this).html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close" aria-hidden="true"></span> Hide');
            hided = false;
            table.destroy();
            table = $('#table_id').DataTable({

                "language": {
                    "url": "http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/3cfcc339e89/i18n/Spanish.json"
                },

                "order": [[ 1, "desc" ]],

                dom: 'TC<"clear">lfrtip',

                oTableTools: {
                    sSwfPath: "http://cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.3/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
                }

            });
        }


    });
});
```

Comment: You should provide an example of this approach.  Dont think a description of a concept really helps ... (no offense at all!)

Comment: @davidkonrad Done, sorry. :)

Comment: supercool, arturo :) You could accept your own answer. Perhaps it will help other people in the future.

Comment: @davidkonrad Yes I will probably do that, but it says I have to wait 2 more days :P